# Conversion failure varchar to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created a Stored Procedure to allow an external system to create an Engineering Notification which is normally handled by a web interface. I've put in a few catches for errors when executed to prevent erroneous data from being input. I am however, getting some conversion errors when I attempt to run.

Example:

`EXEC UDEF_Insert_EN 'WRONGNAME','2316',1002,'Test SP Title','Test SP Comments','A123-457','Z'`

Returns

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '' to data type int
```

The stored procedure looks like this

```
--EXEC UDEF_Insert_EN 'KPark','2316',1002,'Test SP Title','Test SP Comments','A123-457','Z'
--SELECT * FROM _ER2_EN_Details


ALTER Procedure [dbo].[UDEF_Insert_EN]
(
    @Username           nvarchar(50),
    @ER_No              float,
    @EN_Type            int,
    @EN_Title           nvarchar(50),
    @EN_Comments        nvarchar(200),
    @PartNo             nvarchar(16),
    @PartRev            nvarchar(4)
)
As

Declare 
    @ER_ID              float, 
    @User_ID            int,
    @EN_No              float,
    @err_text           nvarchar (200),
    @err_out            tinyint

BEGIN

    Set @err_out = 0
    Set @err_text = 'ERRORS: '
    Set @EN_No = 0


    -- Check if supplied ER Number is valid and if so populate @ER_ID and @EN_No
    If @ER_No in (Select ER_Number from _ER2_Details)
    Begin
        Set @ER_ID = (Select Id from _ER2_Details where @ER_No = ER_Number)     
        Set @EN_No = ISNULL((Select EN_Index from _ER2_Details where @ER_ID = _ER2_Details.Id),1)
    End
    Else
    Begin
        Set @err_text = Char(13) + @ER_No + ' is not a valid ER Number'
        Set @err_out = 1
    End

    -- Check if supplied username is valid and lookup SinglePoint UserID
    If @Username in (Select USR_NAME from USERS)
        Set @User_ID = (Select USR_ID from USERS where USR_NAME = @Username)
    Else
    Begin
        Set @err_text = Char(13) + @err_text + @Username + ' is not a valid Singlepoint user. Ensure the Username matches the Singlepoint Login'
        Set @err_out = 1
    End

    -- Validate @EN_Type parameter
    If  @EN_Type in 
       (    1000, -- New Part
            1001, -- Revised Part
            1002, -- New Assembly
            1003, -- Revised Assembly
            1004, -- New Weldment
            1005, -- Revised Weldment
            1008, -- Third Party Part (8000)
            1009  -- Quick Change
        )   
        Set @EN_Type = @EN_Type
    Else
    Begin
        Set @err_text = Char(13) + @err_text + ' Invalid EN Type'
        Set @err_out = 1
    End


    if @PartNo in (Select EN_Part_Doc_Number from _ER2_EN_Details where @ER_ID = _ER2_EN_Details.ER_ID) and
       @PartRev in (Select EN_Part_Doc_Revision from _ER2_EN_Details where @ER_ID = _ER2_EN_Details.ER_ID)
    Begin
        Set @err_text = Char(13) + @err_text + ' Duplicate EN'
        Set @err_out = 1
    End

    -- Begin Insert
    If @err_out = 0
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO _ER2_EN_Details
    (

        [sys$CreatedBy]     -- Looked up User ID from @UserName parameter
       ,[sys$CreatedAt]     -- DateTime
       ,[sys$ModifiedBy]    -- Looked up User ID from @UserName parameter
       ,[sys$ModifiedAt]    -- DateTime
       ,[ER_ID]             -- Looked up from parameter @ER_No
       ,[EN_Number]         -- Looked up from EN_Index from ER record
       ,[EN_Part_Doc_Number]    -- @PartNo parameter
       ,[EN_Part_Doc_Revision]  -- @PartRev parameter
       ,[EN_Comments]           -- @EN_Comments parameter - Part or revision description
       ,[Date_Created]          -- DateTime
       ,[EN_Status]             -- 1000 (Work in Progress Singlepoint EN status)
       ,[EN_Type]               -- @EN_Type parameter
       ,[EN_Title]              -- @EN_Title parameter - Part Name
       ,[EN_Source]             -- 1002 - Vault Import
    )
    Values 
    (

         @User_ID
        ,GETDATE()
        ,@User_ID
        ,GETDATE()
        ,@ER_ID
        ,@EN_No
        ,@PartNo
        ,@PartRev
        ,@EN_Comments
        ,GETDATE()
        ,1000               -- Status = Work In Progres
        ,@EN_Type
        ,@EN_Title
        ,1002               -- Source = Vault Import
    )

    -- UPDATE _ER2_Details record to increment EN_Index
    UPDATE _ER2_Details
        SET EN_Index = EN_Index + 1
    WHERE _ER2_Details.Id = @ER_ID

    -- Return success message with Singlepoint EN number
    Set @err_text = 'SUCCESS: EN-' + @ER_No + '-' + @EN_No

    END

    Print @err_text
END
```

This is the table definition for the insert

[image: This]

Comment: When you compose the return success message, cast ER_No and EN_No to varchars, that might help.

In what line does the error occur?

Comment: @Alexander That resolves the issue, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line might be causing the error:

```
Char(13) + @ER_No + ' is not a valid ER Number'
```

If you try:

```
DECLARE @ER_No INT = 1

SELECT Char(13) + @ER_No + ' is not a valid ER Number'
```

You will get:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value ' ' to data type int.

You need to cast the numeric value to string before performing concatenation. For example:

```
Char(13) + CAST(@ER_No AS VARCHAR(8)) + ' is not a valid ER Number'
```